# Problemas de sincronizan con pomesas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promesas, axios

Estoy utilizando **axios** en un proyecto de **Vue CLI**.

Para tener mejor estructura en el proyecto estoy haciendo servicios que pueden utilizarse global mente en todo el proyecto.

Un servicio se dedica a consumir una API. Mi problema es la sincronización de la data.

Estoy acostumbrado a utilizar **axios** dentro de los **componentes**. Cosa que ya no are más.

```
axios.get("mi-dominio.com/users").then(
  res=>{
    this.users = res.data;
  },
  err=>{
    this.error = true;
    this.message = err.response.data;
  }
)
```

Ahora lo que intento es utilizar el servicio.

```
import axios from "axios";
class Http {
    async get1() {
        let a;
        await axios.get("https://google.com").then(
            res => {
                a = res;
            },
            err => {
                a = err;
            }
        );
        console.log("a:", a);
        return a;
    }
}
const http = new Http;
export default http;
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando utilizo los métodos de este servicio me regresa una promesa en lugar de la data.

Para los demás servicios o componentes esto debe de ser transparente. Y estos métodos solo deben de regresar datos, no promesas.

Comment: Toda función tipo `async()` devuelve siempre una promesa. ¿Exactamente qué estás esperando que suceda con el resultado? ¿Cómo vas a trabajar con tu método `get1()`? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es debido a que tú método `get1()` de tú clase Http es del tipo `async`, por lo tanto te va retornar una promesa en el lugar que la ejecutes, para evitar ésto puedes hacer nuevamente un `await Http.get1()` en el lugar donde la invoques, o en todo caso en tú metodo `get1()` retornar directamente `axios.get`.

Comment: Y como aria para procesar directamente la promesa en el servicio y que este regrese la pura data de las promesas.

Comment: await http.get1() de esta manera te deberia funcionar

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega, no se puede, es una llamada asíncrona. Siempre vas a tener que o suscribirte al resultado de la promesa (`.then`) o esperar (`await`).